# Excel: Restar fechas en formato "2023-01-01T10:00:00Z"

Tags: excel, power-automate

En un volcado a Excel desde Planner usando Power Automate, las fechas -de inicio y fin de una tarea- aparecen en formato `2023-01-01T10:00:00Z`, que parece ser simplemente una cadena de texto (o al menos Excel no me deja hacer operaciones de tipo resta con ellas, para saber el número de días transcurridos).

¿Hay alguna función que me permita transformar este campo a una fecha -la hora no la necesito tampoco- o simplemente necesito quedarme con los 10 primeros caracteres? Si borro manualmente `T10:00:00Z` y dejo `2023-01-01` veo que Excel ya me permite operar con ellas.

Sería preferible volcar las fechas directamente en el formato que necesito, no sé si es posible tampoco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para transformar la fecha, puedes usar VALOR y IZQUIERDA:

Algo tipo `=VALOR(IZQUIERDA(A1;10))` donde `A1` es la fecha que tienes te transformará el texto en una fecha sin hora según tu configuración regional.

No olvides aplicar formato fecha a la celda o te devolverá solo un número.